Adding Custom Response Headers in a Spring Boot Application with Spring Security
I have a Spring Boot application (2.7.18) with Spring MVC and Spring Security.
I have a a HandlerInterceptor that manages a token bucket with Bucket4j (most of the bucket handling is in a parent class):

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        
        String userId = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        
        boolean interceptorResponse = super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
        
        // TODO: Configure Spring Security to allow this header
        Integer remainingTokens = bucketService.getRemainingTokens(userId);
        response.addHeader("X-Tokens-Remaining", remainingTokens.toString());
        
        if (interceptorResponse) {
            super.bucketService.removeBucket(userId);
        }
        return interceptorResponse;
    }

Spring Security seems to strip the "X-Tokens-Remaining" header.
I've reviewed the documentation here: here. But my question: is it possible to allow this as a configuration item, rather than having to implement a HeaderWriter?
